# Removing sublists from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `C`. I want to remove all sublists which have length 7. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
C = [[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 0, 3, 5], [3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]]

for i in range(0,len(C)):
    if(len(C[i])==7):
        C.remove(C[i])
```

The error is

```
 in <module>
    if(len(C[i])==7):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 0, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: When you remove elements from a list you're iterating over, you may start iterating over indices which are now no longer part of the list. Instead, create a new list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the list you are iterating on, so after you have removed an element, your example list only has length 4, which is why you get this error. To solve this, you need to use an auxiliary list:

```py
result = []
for sublist in C:
    if len(sublist) != 7:
        result.append(sublist)
```

or you can use the builtin `filter`:

```py
list(filter(lambda x: len(x)!= 7, C))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C = [[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 0, 3, 5], [3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]]

new_C = [item for item in C if len(item) != 7]
```